# Use SUBSTRING_INDEX syntax on MySQL database

Tags: mysql, substring

On my MYSQL table I have these string :

```
24015902-C-72
24018504-147
```

I need extract these output :

```
24015902 C-72  
24018504 147
```

And I have tried this query :

```
mysql> SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('24015902-C-72', '-', 1) AS ResultString1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('24015902-C-72', '-', - 1) AS ResultString2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('24018504-147', '-', 1) AS ResultString3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('24018504-147', '-' ,- 1) AS ResultString4;
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| ResultString1 | ResultString2 | ResultString3 | ResultString4 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 24015902      | 72            | 24018504      | 147           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

But on this string `24015902-C-72` the value of `C-` is lost.

How to do resolve this ?

Comment: For me, it works for the first example when using `-2` instead of `-1`. Is there any rule behind this algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delimiter, number)`

- `string`:    `The original string`
- `delimiter` : The delimiter to search for
- `number`: The number of times to search for the delimiter. Can be both a positive or negative number. If it is a positive number, this function returns all to the left of the delimiter. If it is a negative number, this function returns all to the right of the delimiter.

In our case it should work like this for the second statement :

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("24015902-C-72", "-", -2);`